# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3' in zeppelin notebook when used boto3 in UDF's

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, apache-zeppelin

When used boto3 library in user defined function, got the no module found error but the same library is working fine in other paragraphs (when not used in user defined functions).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPxjW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2D9P.png)

Use boto3 module for uploading data to S3 using python in zeppelin notebook

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is zeppelin configured as yarn-client mode and do you have boto3 installed on all of your nodes?